# C# CircularBuffer how to understand readOffset & mCapacityMask

Tags: c#, circular-buffer

I saw a script about CircularBuffer.cs,and i can not understand a case.
This is the whole program:
The case that i can not underatand is " readOffset & mCapacityMask" in function Peek and Write.
I know the result of " readOffset & mCapacityMask ",but i do not know that why the operate can get that reault.

```
internal class CircularBuffer
{

    private byte[] mBuffer = null;
    private int mCapacity = 0;
    private int mCapacityMask = 0;
    private int mHead = 0;
    private int mTail = 0;

    private int PowerOfTwo(int e)
    {
        if (e == 0)
            return 1;

        return 2 * (PowerOfTwo(e - 1));
    }

    public CircularBuffer(int capacityPower)
    {
        mCapacity = PowerOfTwo(capacityPower);
        mCapacityMask = mCapacity - 1;
        mBuffer = new byte[mCapacity];
    }

    public WeakReference GetBuffer()
    {
        return new WeakReference(mBuffer, false);
    }

    public int GetStoredSize()
    {
        if (mHead > mTail)
        {
            return mHead - mTail;
        }
        else if (mHead < mTail)
        {
            return (mCapacity - mTail) + mHead;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public bool Peek(byte[] destBuf, int bytes)
    {
        if (bytes > GetStoredSize())
            return false;

        int readOffset = mTail + bytes;
        int afterReadBytes = readOffset > mCapacity ? readOffset & mCapacityMask : 0;
        int readBytes = bytes - afterReadBytes;
        Buffer.BlockCopy(mBuffer, mTail, destBuf, 0, readBytes);

        if (afterReadBytes > 0)
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(mBuffer, 0, destBuf, readBytes, afterReadBytes);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public bool Read(byte[] destBuf, int bytes)
    {
        if (bytes > GetStoredSize())
            return false;

        int readOffset = mTail + bytes;
        int afterReadBytes = readOffset > mCapacity ? readOffset & mCapacityMask : 0;
        int readBytes = bytes - afterReadBytes;
        Buffer.BlockCopy(mBuffer, mTail, destBuf, 0, readBytes);

        if (afterReadBytes > 0)
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(mBuffer, 0, destBuf, readBytes, afterReadBytes);
        }

        mTail = readOffset & mCapacityMask;

        return true;
    }


    public bool Write(byte[] data, int offset, int bytes)
    {
        if (mCapacity < GetStoredSize() + bytes)
        {
            return false;
        }

        int writeOffset = mHead + bytes;

        int afterWriteBytes = writeOffset > mCapacity ? writeOffset & mCapacityMask : 0;

        int writeBytes = bytes - afterWriteBytes;
        Buffer.BlockCopy(data, offset, mBuffer, mHead, writeBytes);

        if (afterWriteBytes > 0)
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(data, offset + writeBytes, mBuffer, 0, afterWriteBytes);
        }

        mHead = writeOffset & mCapacityMask;

        return true;
    }

    public bool Remove(int bytes)
    {
        if (bytes > GetStoredSize())
            return false;

        mTail = (mTail + bytes) & mCapacityMask;

        return true;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        mHead = 0;
        mTail = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code is expecting the buffer size to be a power of 2.  So mCapacityMask would be something like 0x7FFF.  When offset is greater than mask than location of buffer offset  will be readOffset & mCapacityMask which wraps around from the end of the buffer to the beginning of the buffer.

Comment: so,i can understand that is a "take Remainder"  operatation。thank you。I think，I have understanded.